# Replace NA with 0 in R

Tags: r

How do I replace 'NA' within a data frame with zeros in R? I tried the following but I get this error: Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, is.na(data), value = 0) :
unsupported matrix index in replacement

```
data[is.na(data)] <- 0
```

Thank you!

Comment: You should apply it to a column, e.g. `data$col1[is.na(data$col1)] <- 0`

Comment: That's strange. Please, consider posting the output of `dput(head(data))`, so we can have a reproducible example and guess what's going on.

Comment: As nicola said, but we could probably guess what the issue is just by running `str(data)`.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `tidyr` for this.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
    x = c(NA, NA, 1),
    y = c(1, 2, NA)
)

df
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>       x     y
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1    NA     1
#> 2    NA     2
#> 3     1    NA

df %>%
    mutate(
        across(everything(), replace_na, 0)
    )
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>       x     y
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     0     1
#> 2     0     2
#> 3     1     0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score -1):

The ImputeTS has a useful function called `imputeTS::replace_na()` that should replace all NA values with 0s in a dataframe.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(imputeTS)


df <- tribble(~T1, ~T2,
        1, NA,
        3, NA, 
        NA, 4,
        NA, NA)

imputeTS::na_replace(df)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>      T1    T2
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     0
#> 2     3     0
#> 3     0     4
#> 4     0     0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: I'd appreciate any feedback if this anser isn't useful.